# Jquery in Django: Which django apps should I look into?

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-apps

I want to use some jquery in my forms and I was hoping to use some ready made solutions - there seem to be a lot of them...

Which django apps would you recommend for this purpose? Which are most popular?

**EDIT #1:**
Hmmmm... I suppose I didn't put enough effort into my question... I was hoping for more options/clarifications...

There seems to be a huge amount of jquery apps out there. Here's a random selection:

- [django-ajax-selects](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/) - for autocompleting ManyToManyFields and ForeignKeys
- [django-autocomplete](http://code.google.com/p/django-autocomplete/) - same as above
- [django-ajax-filtered-fields](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/) - autocomplete yet again
- [django-easywidgets](http://code.google.com/p/django-easywidgets/) - this one doesn't seem to be documented on-line, so I'm not sure what it does, but it's probably a collection of widgets.
- [django-ajax-forms](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-forms/) - already mentioned by silent1mezzo, from what I can see it does client side validation
- [django-dynamic-formset](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/) - adding new forms to an already rendered formset
- [django-form-widgets](http://code.google.com/p/django-form-widgets/) - a collection of widgets like datapicker etc.

I suppose the obvious answer is "use the one that gives you the functionality you need", as most of these serve different purposes. But I was wondering which are commonly used... Or maybe most people just tend to code their own?

For someone who is pretty clueless about jquery is it easier to use one or a few of these? Or is it easier to do it "by hand"?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a few examples

Ajax Contact Form http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/992/

django-ajax-forms http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-forms/

Here's a tutorial if you want to get your hands dirty
http://dewful.com/?p=100

Comment: The links may indeed prove useful :) But could you elaborate a bit? I see two of the links aren't apps, but jquery + django examples. One is an app - why did you recommend that particular one?